# Google removing full path in search results

Tags: google, blog, search-results, rich-snippets

Just noticed something strange and would like to see if anyone knows why this is happening. On my own website and [the BYBE blog](https://www.bybe.net/blog/) the pages that appear in Google's search results do not return the full path, it reveals the parent blog page but nothing more.

Here is a screenshot to give you more of an idea what is happening:
[image: BYBE Screenshot]

As you can it displays `www.bybe.net > Blog` when in fact I would hope it would display `www.bybe.net > Blog > Essential Designer Sites`, or the real path which is https://www.bybe.net/essential-web-design-websites/. I suspect this could be happening because I don't use /blog/article-name/ and opt to use /article-name/ but I'm not sure... or the fact that I'm using Yoast SEO and the [breadcrumbs looks like this](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/?url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.bybe.net%252Fessential-web-design-websites%252F):

```
Breadcrumb
url: https://www.bybe.net/
title: Home

child [Breadcrumb]:
url: https://www.bybe.net/blog/
title: Blog
```

Note that this question may be duplicate as I can't believe that I'm the only person experiencing this issue. I've checked but people word things differently and I may have missed it, if you know of a similar question then by all means flag this as duplicate and I'll or another moderator will take action, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is really an answer, more an observation, but anyway...

It seems that if Google is able to extract an obvious breadcrumb trail from the page then it will show this in the search results, rather than the actual URL.

The breadcrumb trail in the SERPs *never* includes the final (leaf) page, only the breadcrumb trail that leads to that page (so it often only represents the parent category). The *title* in the SERPs is the final page.

In your case, the breadcrumb trail leading to your page is simply "Home > Blog", so this is all you see in the SERPs. The title of the search result is the final page.

Comment: Bingo!! I noticed this too and largely gave up on breadcrumbs partly because of this and how inconsistently Google displays them- say, 200 pages, Google may show breadcrumbs of 97 even though they are generated using the exact same code method and 100% correct. I said good-bye to breadcrumbs philosophically a year ago and will be actually removing 3/4's of them really really soon with something else.

Comment: At the rate google is behaving lately, its no wonder why I use yandex and bing webmaster tools as well to try to get my pages indexed.